# Sega Saturn HD404920 microcontroller SMPC details

Tags: sega

Does anyone have any details of the Sega Saturn's HD404920 microcontroller, which serves as the "System Manager & Peripheral Control" (SMPC)?

A datasheet, pinout, extracted ROM code... There doesn't appear to be any data online at all.

The reason I ask is that this part is the main cause of high battery drain in the Sega Saturn. If it could be replaced with a more modern MCU, battery drain could be greatly reduced. I believe it also handles controller I/O.

Comment: You mean the battery used to keep save game states, or are you somehow running your entire Saturn off a battery?

Comment: The battery for save states and the clock. Replacing the save state memory with FRAM is no problem, but you still have the issue of the clock being lost every time the battery dies.

Answer (score 1):

[Yabause](https://yabause.org) is an emulator for the Sega Saturn, so I'd assume it also has to emulate the SMPC at least to some degree.

[Here](http://wiki.yabause.org/index.php5?title=SMPC) is their wiki entry of the SMPC, which has a memory map, and port pinouts.

So potentially they have ROM dumps or disassemblies, or a datasheet. I'd try to [contact them](https://yabause.org/contact/) and find out - maybe the email address still works, even though it says it's archived content.

There is also a [die shot](https://siliconpr0n.org/archive/doku.php?id=d356:sega:315-5744_smpc) of the HD404920FS.

Datasheets for the HD404918/HD404919 are available via google, e.g. [here](https://retrocdn.net/images/8/8c/HD40491_datasheet.pdf).

On the corresponding [wikichip page](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/hitachi/hmcs400), there is also a manual for the whole [HMCS400 Series](https://en.wikichip.org/w/images/0/0e/HMCS400_Series_Manual_%281988%29.pdf) including instruction set and pinout for different packages.

The only open question is what differences the HD404920 had compared to the other models.

You should be able to get the on-chip ROM contents from the decapped die shot, various toolkits for this are available on the internet (but I haven't used one of those myself).

Comment: Thanks. The source for Yabause has the SMPC driver here: https://github.com/Yabause/yabause/tree/master/yabause/src (smpc.c and smpc.h). Some useful info in there.

Comment: Unfortunately the pinout is for the controller port, not the IC. It looks like it has a fairly standard bus connection, but not sure about the connection to the ports.

Comment: HD404918/HD404919 datasheets have IC pinouts, so compare those with connections on your board, to the controller ports and elsewhere? That should give you at least some estimate as a start.